# Help me transfer contacts to new phone

Tags: iphone

So my mom just bought a new Iphone 7 and she wants me to transfer **ONLY** her contacts to her new phone but cant i just login in with the apple ID on the New phone and everything would restore on it? If not please show a easy way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, contacts are linked to your Apple ID. To import them, just to go Settings > iCloud on both the old and new phone and enable contacts.

After that, go into the contacts app on the new phone and hit the refresh button. Her contacts should appear shortly.